# Bootstrap 4: Responsive Button with an Icon on the Left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Whatever I do, the button just comes out gimmicky. And too complicated. It breaks apart on smaller screens and does not behave naturally at all. Especially when I include it in a column. Can someone please tell me the correct and clean way to do this? I really need this to be as simple as it can and not fall apart when I include it in different components in Bootstrap 4.

Anyway, here's my code. I'm using Bootstrap 4 and FontAwesome. I've placed it deliberately in a column, so you can see that the text, for example, is not center aligned properly. Is this the correct way to go?

```css
.btn {
   border: none;
   padding: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   position: relative;
      background: #42473d;
   color: #fff;
  }

.btn:before {
 font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 line-height: 2.9;
 font-size: 18px;
 width: 50px;
    content: "\f09a";
    background-color: #292c26;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
  <button class="btn btn-block rounded-0">View Using Facebook</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <button class="btn btn-block rounded-0">Sign in with Facebook</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positioning is not required in this case for `.btn:before`. Also instead of `line-height` you should use `padding` to define the area. Adjust the `margin-left` and `margin-right` instead of `left` and `right`.

I've added an additional `margin-bottom` to the `.btn` class. You can remove it if you don't need it.

```css
.btn {
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  background: #42473d;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  content: "\f09a";
  background-color: #292c26;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 mb-2">
  <button class="btn btn-block rounded-0">View Using Facebook</button>
</div>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <button class="btn btn-block rounded-0">Sign in with Facebook</button>
</div>
```

[Update]
In case the button is a `btn-block`; it's best to use `em` units instead of `px`.
https://jsfiddle.net/mr6nt5no/4/

Comment: Yes, but my buttons are .btn-block. They stretch to the entire width of the container. If I apply your styling with that, I get this: http://pokit.org/get/img/b30c61b36780f970c48a038712a361e4.jpg

Comment: Also, what happens if I use different icons, with different width? Will I have to style their container separately, to match the one above: http://pokit.org/get/img/c805673f992c67d63055b76321b933f9.jpg  Is there no simpler way to do this?

Comment: If the buttons are `btn-block` then you are better off using `em` instead of `px` as units. https://jsfiddle.net/mr6nt5no/3/

Comment: And https://jsfiddle.net/mr6nt5no/4/ works with different icons as well without any styling differences.